# Is there a word that means "as its name would suggest"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does there exist a single word that more or less means "as its name would suggest"? For example, is there a word that appropriately might replace the bolded portion of the following sentence?

> Computer Science, **as its name would suggest**, is the science of computation.

Something perhaps in the vein of the following?

> Computer Science, **unsurprisingly**, is the science of computation.

Comment: The closest I could come was [eponym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym) which isn't quite correct as it means, "name of someone attached to an object." Maybe it will trigger someone's memory.

Comment: *Eponymous* usually only gets used either to avoid repeating oneself (when talking about both the original *and* the thing sharing its name), or to explicitly state the connection if it might not be known to whoever you're talking to. Not the right word here, but definitely a good one to have in your vocabulary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting word. Out of curiosity, would you provide examples of both of the use cases you mentioned?

Comment: The Roches released their eponymous first album in 1979 (I wouldn't want to explicitly name both the group and the album in a single utterance). Though things get awkward with the REM album actually *called* "Eponymous"...

Comment: Gabriele Fallopio studied the eponymous tubes, to the immense subsequent benefit of millions of women.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps:

> The discipline 'Computer Science',
>   fittingly, is the science of
>   computation.

or

> The discipline 'Computer Science' is
>   aptly named; it is the science of
>   computation.

Informally, I see increasing usage of "well" as an obvious connotation:

> Computer Science is, well, the science
>   of computation.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the informal use of "well." For the style of writing I tend to do, it seems like the best fit.

Comment: Well, +1 for *well*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is *No*.

The long answer (as its name would suggest) is that there are lots of words and phrases which in context mean *as [that name] would suggest*. Such as *obviously*, *self-evidently*, *as you can guess*, *unsurprisingly*, etc. But *as you might expect*, none of them are really necessary, since you're already assuming the hearer knows what you're saying anyway.

Notwithstanding Shakespeare's observations on [What's in a name](http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/what-s-name-that-which-we-call-rose), people usually *do* try to assign meaningful names to new things that need naming. We can't really do that with babies, because we don't really know what they will be like when they grow up. But marketing departments, for example, spend a lot of time trying to come up with names that somehow suit their new products.

Answer (score 1):

Eponymous, the adjective form of eponym: one for whom or which something is believed to be named. Merriam Webster Collegiate Dictionary.

Computer Science is the eponymous science of computation.

Answer (score 0):

Although not strictly English, the Latin phrase "nomen est omen" (literally "the name is an omen") seems to get the message across. I would much rather stay away from Latin, hence how I found this page.

Comment: Not strictly English at all in fact.

Answer (score 0):

How about xxx personifies its name by...(doing as it's name suggests)...

Comment: Gives its name human characteristics?

Answer (score -1):

In the case of a person's name there is "aptronym", meaning a personal name aptly or peculiarly suited to its owner, such as a rich person with the last name of Flush, or a hairdresser whose last name is Cutter.

Reference:  [Wikipedia, Aptronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym):

> Aptronym, aptonym or euonym are rarely-encountered neologisms for the
>   concept of nominative determinism, used for a personal name aptly or
>   peculiarly suited to its owner; essentially, when someone's name
>   describes what they are or what they do.
>
> In the book What's in a Name? (1996), author Paul Dickson cites a long
>   list of aptronyms originally compiled by Professor Lewis P. Lipsitt,
>   of Brown University. Psychologist Carl Jung wrote in his book Synchronicity that there was a "sometimes quite grotesque coincidence between a man's name and his peculiarities".

Comment: Hello, Anne L.  Note my edit.  Your future answers should contain source and link.

Comment: Aptronyms ('peculiarly suited ...') hardly matches 'unsurprisingly'.

Answer (score -2):

I've been in several situations which made me which I had a shorthand for "as the name suggests". After much digging around and finding nothing, I figured that the English language need not constrain itself to commonly used combinations of roots and _fixes. I've coined "nomenous" for this.

"nomen" -- the Latin root for "name" or "title", and 
"ous" -- the Anglo-French from Latin "osus", meaning "full of" or "having the quality of"

So...

> Nom•e•nous
>
> *adjective*
>
> having qualities suggested by its name
>
> "My TI-503 is a nomenous calculator"

Now we need an adverb form of it... "nomenously"?